# in laravel how to get duration value with column join date and completion date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**i am trying to display duration value, using database "column name" ( "date_of_join" ,"date_of_completion")   value in view**

like ( 1/1/2018 to 1/1/2019 )  this value show like ( **1 year** )

( 1/1/2018 to 1/2/2018 ) value show like ( **1 month** )

( 1/1/2018 to 10/2/2018 ) value show like (**1 month 10 days** )

**how to do this in laravel**
**how to show y=this in view**

**my view**

```
    @if(isset($details))

    <table class="table table-striped">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PHOTO</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>CERTIFICATE NO</th>
                    <th>COURSE</th>
                    <th>COURSE DURATION</th>
                    <th>DATE OF JOIN</th>
                    <th>CENTER NAME</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach($details as $user)
              <td> 
                <td>{{$user->student_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->student_registration_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->student_course}}</td>
                <td>{{                     }}</td>
                <td>{{$user->date_of_join}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->center_name}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @elseif(isset($message))
    <p style="color:red" align="center">{{$message}}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

**my route**

```
Route::any( '/search', function(){
  $id = Input::get( 'id' );
  $certificate_issue_date = Input::get('certificate_issue_date');
  if($id != ""){

   $user = Student::where( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%' );
   if (!empty($certificate_issue_date))
    {
       $user->where('certificate_issue_date','=',$certificate_issue_date)->where('student_certificate_approval', 'APPROVED');
    }
        $user = $user->get();

        if (count ( $user ) > 0)
     return view( 'verify_certificate' )->withDetails( $user )->withQuery($id)->withDateOfJoin($certificate_issue_date);
     }
  return view ( 'verify_certificate' )->withMessage ( "No Details found!" );
  } );
```

Comment: @TsaiKoga what is the good idea to put logic in different location

Comment: Use `Mutators`, put the logic in model. View is just used to display datas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators);

And use `Carbon` to get the duration（for examples: diffInSeconds, diffInDays, diffForHumans, etc）

If you want the accurate format like that, you need to write it a method.

In your Student model:

```php
Class Student extend Model
{
    ...
    public function getDurationAttribute() {
        return Student::diffToHumanInterval($this->date_of_join, $this->date_of_completion);
    }

    public static function diffToHumanInterval($start, $end) {
        $human = '';
        $start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($start);
        $end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($end);
        $years = $end_date->diffInYears($start_date);
        if ($years > 0) { 
            $human = $human.$years.' years ';
            $start_date = $start_date->addYears(years);
        }
        $months = $end_date->diffInMonths($start_date);
        if ($months > 0) {
            $human = $human.$months.' months ';
            $start_date = $start_date->addMonths($months);
        }
        $days = $end_date->diffInDays($start_date);
        if ($days > 0) {
            $human = $human.$days.' days ';
            $start_date = $start_date->addDays($days);
        }
        return $human;
    }
    ...
}
```

In your view:

```php
<td>{{  $user->duration  }}</td>
```

Comment: @user12380208 it's not random numbers, is the duration seconds between these two date. I have changed to human language.

Comment: its showing error Use of undefined constant days - assumed 'days' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: @user12380208 I forget to add `$` before days. I have updated...

Comment: output result is "days" i what to show like ( 1 month or 1 year )

Comment: @user12380208 My mistakes, I have updated the answer .

Answer (score 2):

This is simple with PHP

```
 <?php 
  $datetime1 = new DateTime($date_of_join);
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($date_of_completion);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
  $days = $interval->format('%a'); // only days you will get.
 ?>
```

You can then convert days in Months and Years as you want.

Edit :

You have to pass `date_of_completion` as well in below line

```
 return view( 'verify_certificate' )->withDetails( $user )->withQuery($id)->withDateOfJoin($certificate_issue_date);
```

In view

```
 @foreach($details as $user)
   @php
     $datetime1 = new DateTime($user->date_of_join);
     $datetime2 = new DateTime($user->date_of_completion);
     $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

     $days = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds'); 
   @endphp
     <td> 
     <td>{{$user->student_name}}</td>
     <td>{{$user->student_registration_id}}</td>
     <td>{{$user->student_course}}</td>
     <td>{{$days}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->date_of_join}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->center_name}}</td>
</tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: @Prashanth Deshmukh i was updated my ,view and route , please check and add guide me how to add your logic in my code thank you

Comment: @user12380208 Hope updated answer will give some idea to you.

Comment: @Prashanth Deshmukh its showing error "Undefined variable: date_of_completion"

Comment: @user12380208 check now

Comment: @Prashanth Deshmukh its showing error DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/12/2019) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character"

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<?php 
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2019-11-11");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2020-11-12");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
echo $elapsed;
?>
```

refer link [referlinkwithexample](https://paiza.io/projects/1REY94YulqzHy1UMdFymKQ)

```
 @foreach($details as $user)
   @php
     $datetime1 = new DateTime($user->date_of_join);
     $datetime2 = new DateTime($user->date_of_completion);
     $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
     $days = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds'); 
   @endphp
     <td> 
     <td>{{$user->student_name}}</td>
     <td>{{$user->student_registration_id}}</td>
     <td>{{$user->student_course}}</td>
     <td>{{$days}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->date_of_join}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->center_name}}</td>
</tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: i was updated my ,view and route , please check and add guide me how to add your logic in my code thank you

Comment: i got error #message: "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/12/2019) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character"
  #code: 0

Comment: in localhost its working when i shift the code on line its showing error

Comment: your answer working perfect in local , but online its not working

Comment: please give upvote this answer THANK YOU!!@user12380208

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon

`$date->diffInDays($dateCondition);` //result how many days left

```
diffInYears, diffInMonths
```